# simple_html_dom issues with finding a specific class

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

The following is my code:

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$rowdate;

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('http://www.forexfactory.com/calendar.php');

foreach($html->find('.calendar_row') as $e)
{

$date=$e->find('span.date');
if ($date[0] != "")
    {
    $rowdate=$date[0];
    }   
$time=$e->find('.time');
$currency=$e->find('.currency');    
$impact=$e->find('.impact');
$event=$e->find('.event');  

echo $rowdate;echo ",";
echo $time[0];echo ",";
echo $currency[0];echo ",";
echo $impact[0];echo ",";
echo $event[0];
echo "<br>";    

}
```

The above code works fine however **$impact is not displayed at all** while if you open the url in your browser directly and see the source code , we can see that the impact class is present within each calendar_row

Can anyone please guide me as to what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: The impact class is present, but those cells look like this: `<td class="impact"> <span title="Medium Impact Expected" class="medium"></span></td>`. In other words, they don't contain text, only an empty span element.

Comment: Hi @GolezTrol , what would be the best way to get the value of them? I just need to show the impact level , high , medium and low .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$impact = $e->find('.impact');
echo $impact[0];
```

You want:

```
$impact = $e->find('.impact', 0);
echo $impact;
```

And you probably *really* want:

```
$impact = $e->find('.impact span', 0)->class;
```

Read the simple html dom documentation if you don't understand why.

Comment: Hi Thanks ! this works, now going to read the documentation to understand the reason behind this.